# Time management for real-time applications

Tags: python, sleep, python-multithreading

How to generate precise pulses with python?

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def runA():
    while True:
        print "a"
        sendSignal(1)
        time.sleep(0.0001)
        sendSignal(0)
        time.sleep(0.005)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = Thread(target = runA)
    t1.setDaemon(True)
    t1.start()
    while True:
        sleep(10)
```

time management in python is not precise. specially to create multi-threaded PWM generators (assuming each thread to send data at specific rate) . is there any better way to generate pulses? precise ones!

[The solution is language-independent]

Comment: `This code does not print "a" 10 times every second` - What does it do?

Comment: it prints "a" on random intervals, but it should be printing a 10 times each second

Comment: well, it would print it about 10 times per second of that thread's execution time.  If the CPU is really busy you might end up with it being less regular than that

Comment: running the function `runA()` directly (not within a thread) does not have any problems. CPU load is 0% (running linux without a UI - just command line + SSH)

Comment: The CPU shouldn't be zero, since your main thread appears to run a continuous loop and should therefore be getting much more CPU time than the sleeping sub-thread.

Comment: I ran the code exactly as is, unchanged, and it works exactly the same under python3 and python2-- python2 behaves exactly the same as python3.

Comment: Try this on ARM processor (raspi 2)

Comment: @holdenweb yes you are right. Does python support timers?

Comment: You can use time.sleep() to sleep a thread. So you might try a `sleep(0.1)` instead of `pass` in your main thread's loop

Comment: @holdenweb I understand this frees up some time for other code to run in the processor, but still it will not be precise right? i need it to be precise to 1ms for PWM generation. and this won't fix it. ... i guess i will change my question.

Comment: I suspect you may be struggling to achieve that level of precision without using a specialized OS (such as one for embedded systems). I would also point out the 0.0001sec is one-tenth of a millisecond, not that I understand your issues fully.

Comment: @holdenweb with a single loop in a single thread i tried a 5 millisecond delays and it worked, but had +- 1 millisecond from time to time. whemever there's another thread running the error margin increases. what specialised OS can achive that? will itnrun python?

Comment: I'm not an embedded systems expert, I'm afraid. You should be looking at QNX and similar systems. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402933/python-on-an-real-time-operation-system-rtos) might shed more light on the subject for you.

Comment: Sounds exactly what i need. can you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution was to find a real-time OS
Actually raspberry pi have a real-time patch for the raspbian OS

For more information : https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=39951

Was a little of a challenge to enable it. but it is working and the error rate dropped dramatically.

Thank you @holdenweb for the tip with the real-time OS

Answer (score -1):

Your output is probably buffered so you'll get a big block of them printed all at once.  You could try flushing stdout after each print like

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: It is not about the `stdout`. the `print "a"` is just an example of whatever function I need. the original is a function to send data through a socket ... another function is PWM generation